Why is my YOLO-v8 TFLite model slower than my Pytorch model?
I originally had a trained Pytorch YOLO-v8 nano model, for multi-object detection in videos (10 classes - "Bicycle", "Chair", "Box", "Table", "Plastic bag", "Flowerpot", "Luggage and bags", "Umbrella", "Shopping trolley", "Person").
I converted it into a TFLite model using the ultralytics library's export function. However, when I run both models on a video stream, my TFLite model runs considerably slower (FPS around 8) than my Pytorch model (FPS around 20). Why is this so?
Both TFLite and Pytorch models are here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1A2XUD5sV332nXv-Z756Di_QUIZV3ObFv?usp=sharing
Conversion from trained Pytorch model to tflite model.
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("yolov8n_trained.pt")
path = model.export(format="tflite") 

Running video stream on model:
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from time import time

# Start webcam
stream_url = "video_stream_path" 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url) # Use 0 for webcam
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 640)

# Load your retrained YOLOv8 model 
model = YOLO("yolov8n_trained.tflite")   # use this when testing tflite model
# model = YOLO("yolov8n_trained.pt")     # use this when testing pytorch model

# Custom class names
classNames = ["Bicycle", "Chair", "Box", "Table", "Plastic bag", "Flowerpot", 
              "Luggage and bags", "Umbrella", "Shopping trolley", "Person"]

# initialise variables to calculate frame rate
prev_time = 0
fps = 0

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    if not success:
        break

    #Calculate time taken to process frame
    curr_time = time()
    fps = 1 / (curr_time - prev_time)
    prev_time = curr_time

    #Display frame rate on image
    cv2.putText(img, f"FPS: {fps:.2f}", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), 1)

    # Run the YOLO model on the image
    results = model(img, stream=True)

    # Process detection results
    for r in results:
        for box in r.boxes:
            # Extract bounding box coordinates and confidence
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, box.xyxy[0])  # Convert to integer
            confidence = box.conf[0]                # Confidence score
            class_id = box.cls[0]                   # Class ID

            # Draw bounding box
            color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green color for bounding box
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, 2)

            # Draw label with class name and confidence
            label = f"{classNames[int(class_id)]}: {confidence:.2f}"
            label_size, base_line = cv2.getTextSize(label, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
            y1 = max(y1, label_size[1])
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1 - label_size[1]), (x1 + label_size[0], y1 + base_line), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, label, (x1, y1), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 1)

    # Display webcam feed
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

# Release resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



There is a year-old unresolved bug related to this problem: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/1293

Yes, I came across that site. But no answer there for the issue.
